# Children's rights (Son)

Tags: fiqh, sunni, hanafi, parents, obligation

I've heard that the father is responsible for his children in-terms of clothing them, providing them with food, shelter (financially to put it simply), as in all the basics of life.

Assuming this is true (if it's not true, let me know and I will delete this question), does Islam specify how long the father is responsible for his son?

For example, if the son is 25 years old and the father is 45 years old, and both the father and son are working.  Is the father still responsible for providing his son with cloths, food, shelter etc?  I would assume no, but want to get the Islamic view on this.

So my question is this: Is the father responsible for his son financially until the father dies?  Or does this responsibility end when the son starts earning or when the son reaches a certain age?  Maybe when the son reaches adulthood?

Comment: father is responsible for his children till they are depended on him (age no bar) when child starts earning father is not responsible for his child.

Comment: @Zia, any fatwa/quranic/or hadith verse about this?  What happens if the son is lazy and can't be bothered to work?  Or decides to education until the son is 50 years old?  With that in mind, the answer below seems to make more sense then your comment.

Comment: i am talking about general case. laziness and other reason are special cases that you didn't mentioned in your question. by the way it is the responsibility of son to take care of his parents when they are old.

Comment: So the fatwa below is wrong which says that the fathers financial responsibility on his sons ends when the son reaches puberty?

Comment: if you think the below fatwa is right then please apply this on you and your child. as son attains puberty by the age of 14 generally and at that age he did not have completed his 10 years of basic education.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding my question.  Based on that fatwa, it seems that the responsibility has been removed from the father when the son reaches puberty.  That doesn't mean that it becomes haraam for the father to look after his child...

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic talking about the subject (Arabic) [here](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=102192)

> وأما عن السن الذي تنتهي فيه مسؤولية الأبوين عن أبنائهم فسبق أنها إلى
>   البلوغ، أما بعد البلوغ فالمسؤولية تقع عليهم، ولا يبقى على الوالدين إلا
>   النصح والتوجيه والأمر بالمعروف والنهي عن المنكر، شأنهما في ذلك مع
>   أولادهما شأن المسلم مع أخيه المسلم.

So according to this fatwa, parents responsibility ends towards their children for supporting them ends on puberty, after that each one is responsible on himself, and remains on the parents the responsibility of advice and guidance.